# Problem Submitting Html Form with Python's Mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to login into the website http://ogame.us using python to access the data. After looking around the web to find out how to attempt to do this, I settled on using the mechanize module. I think I have the general gist of the code down, but when I submit the html form nothing happens. Here's the code:

```
import sys,os
import mechanize, urllib
import cookielib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup,BeautifulStoneSoup,Tag
import datetime, time, socket
import re,sys,os,mechanize,urllib,time,  urllib2


br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

# User-Agent (this is cheating, ok?)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US;    rv:1.9.0.6')]
br.open('http://ogame.us')

br.select_form(name = 'loginForm' )

br['login'] = 'stackexample'
br['pass'] = 'examplepassword'
br['uni_url'] = ['uni103.ogame.us']

br.submit()

print br.geturl()
```

The response from geturl() is the same url that I was at before. Anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a third field (uni) that I was not completing. Everything else was correct.

In the future, with Google Chrome (and probably other browsers) you can view the actual requests sent to the browser by opening Chrome Developer Tools and looking under network. This saves quite a bit of time.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    data = br.submit()
    html=data.read()
```

Comment: It didn't seem to do the trick. When I printed html I got the html from the login screen and geturl() still returned the login url.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe select the button directly?

```
response = br.submit(type="submit", id="loginSubmit")
```

Comment: Again, nothing. This code did work on other websites, too, which puzzles me.

Comment: have you tried putting braces around login and password? `br['login'] = ['stackexample'] br['pass'] = ['examplepassword']` Maybe you need to also simulate pressing on the login button that makes the login menu pop up, although I doubt thats it.